# ¿Como puedo pasar datos de react a php?

Tags: php, react-hooks

Como podría pasar datos de react a php y siendo asi como puedo recibirlo en php e intentado con axion pero no me llegan los datos y no se como recibirlo en php

const [DatosRecibidos, setDatosRecibidos] = useState({});

```
useEffect(()=>{
    const api = axios.create({baseURL : "http://localhost"})
    api.post("/api-php-react/cargar_col.php" , Datos )
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
```

esto seria lo que tendria en php

```
  include_once ('corn.php');
if (isset($_POST)) {
   echo "si hay datos post";
   echo 'hay'.count($_POST);
   $var = $_POST ['idAdmin'];
   echo $var;
    echo json_encode(array('mensaje'=>'si llegaron'));
}else{
    echo "no datos";
}

?>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Te fijaste con f12 que datos van en la llamada? Que tiene datos? y tu back que tiene?

Comment: Tienes que poner ```$_POST['variable_que_recibes']```

Comment: ya lo coloque asi y lo actualice y quedo algo asi

Comment: @David Capera Herrera Te funcionó?

Comment: realmente no pero si encontré la solución

Comment: este fue el que puse y me permitió recibir los datos $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));